# CSS/Design files aren't loading

Tags: css, images, webserver, design, opencart

I've transferred my OpenCart site to a new hosting. I've followed every step from this tutorial (https://isenselabs.com/posts/step-by-step-opencart-migration-to-a-new-server).

My transfer is complete now. Database and other necessary files are imported already. Even I can access the page also (`http://www.example.com/test`), but the problem is design file is not loading at all. There is no design and image at all. I can't understand where is the problem. How can I overcome the issue.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but the question was placed on hold because the question is unclear and too specific. Unclear: questions should be answerable without having to visit a site to diagnosis the issue. Too Specific: Questions should help further visitors of the site, correct format does not help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that you set the base href as `http://example.com/test/` and trying to load your css and images from there. I would suggest changing it to `http://example.com/test`

Comment: Thanks @tonydoe for your response. Could you please clarify more. Actually I can't understand How can I change the base href?

Comment: `/test/` is not set within your WordPress install. Edit wp-config.php and add both `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/test/');`  `define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/test/');`

Comment: Thanks everyone. Superb answer. My problem is solved. :)